# Vagrant box or any VMs to simulates Open Build System environments

Tags: packaging, rpm, deb

Is there a vagrant box or any other kind of VMs that simulates Open Build System environments?

I'd like to make sure my package works fine locally before sending it to the building system. The problem is many times my local environments have more stuff installed or different version from the building environment.

I think that having a local VM to simulate the environments would be ideal but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I don't use OBS nor have I tried this myself.

OBS has an appliance that likely can be run in vagrant/vbox here:

```
https://en.opensuse.org/openSUSE:Build_Service_Appliance
```